# ¿Cómo pasar usuario y contraseña por url para autentificación básica despues de la actualizacion de chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, chrome

Con la reciente actualización de chrome https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 bloquea las url's que llevan usuario y contraseña en la url `http://usuario:password@www.sitio.com`. Alguien sabe como resolver esto, ya que ocupo unas imagenes de otra página la cual tengo usuario y contraseña. utilizo angularjs y simplemente actualizo la url de cada 3 segundos poniendo la cadena de tiempo al final de la url porque así se guardan las imagenes en la otra página el cual cabe mencionar que no tengo acceso a base de datos ni a código, simplemente una url, usuario y contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco tu caso particular, pero no es una buena práctica mandar user y password en la url. Las URLs se cachean y loguean, y los usuarios las copian y mandan por mail.

Para basic authorization podes mandar un header

```
'Authorization: basic usuario:password'
```